# Wide Range of the same Color in R

Tags: r, colors, color-palette

Is it possible to create *great number* of different kinds of "red" color. For better understanding I am expecting following, but instead of grey I desire to have "red" or "red-black".

```
mypalette <- rev(grey.colors(10000, start = 0.1, end = 0.5, gamma = 4))
plot(1:length(mypalette),1:length(mypalette), col=mypalette, pch=16)
```

The color packages I know have *limited range of colors*. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: `color.gradient(c(1, 1), c(1, 0), c(0, 0), nslices = 10)` from `plotrix` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, try `colorRampPalette`. It returns a function that outputs the requested number of colours between the two you specified.

```
reds <- colorRampPalette(c("black","red"))
reds(5)
[1] "#000000" "#3F0000" "#7F0000" "#BF0000" "#FF0000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some `ggplot` alternatives

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), z = rnorm(100), z2 = factor(1:5))

# colour set by continuous variable
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = z)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "red", high = "white")
```

[image]

```
library(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = z)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = brewer.pal(5, "Reds"))
```

[image]

```
# colour set by discrete variable
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = z2)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Reds")
```

[image]